# Connection closed before receiving a handshake response WebSocket

Tags: javascript

im trying to connect my client through web sockets in JS but I have this error

```
getUser.js:29 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8005/wsserver.js' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response
```

But look my code:

getUser.js

```
var sock = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8005/wsserver.js");

$('#data1').append("alors");

sock.onopen = function (event) {     
  $('#data').append("server status opened" + event.currentTarget.URL);
  sock.send(JSON.stringify("coucou"));
  console.log("sended");
};
sock.onmessage = function (event) {
 $('#data').append(event.data);
 console.log(event.data);
};
sock.onerror = function(error) {
  console.log('WebSocket Error: ' + error);
};
```

And the server side code is:
wsserver.js

```
var WebSocketServer = require("ws").Server;
var ws = new WebSocketServer( { port: 8005 } );

console.log("Server started...");

ws.on('connection', function (ws) {
  console.log("Browser connected online...")

  ws.on("message", function (str) {
     var ob = JSON.parse(str);
     switch(ob.type) {
     case 'text':
         console.log("Received: " + ob.content)
         ws.send('{ "type":"text", "content":"Server ready."}')
         break;
     case 'image':
         console.log("Received: " + ob.content)         
         console.log("Here is an apricot...")
         var path ="apricot.jpg";   
         var data = '{ "type":"image", "path":"' + path + '"}';
         ws.send(data); 
         break;
      }   
    })

    ws.on("close", function() {
        console.log("Browser gone.")
    })
});
```

But the error is still here, i don't understand why

Answer (score 1):

Take script part away from your client:

var sock = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8005");

Server app is running in that port and all you need is to connect to the port.